# Регулярное выражение, для чисел с разделителем запятой между каждыми тремя цифрами

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Как записать регулярное выражение, которому соответствуют числа с запятой в качестве разделителя между каждыми тремя цифрами?

Этому выражению должны соответствовать эти числа: `41`, `1,234`, `6,368,745`.
И не должны соответствовать следующие: `12,34,567`, `1234`

Простым способом через циклы решается, а вот как через рег. выражения никак. Остановился вот на этом.

```
import re

numberRegex = re.compile(r'\d{,3}')
mo = numberRegex.findall('34441234')
print(mo)
```

Comment: Я неправильно понял смысл задачи. Думал, что число, которые введет пользователь, надо разбивать по тройкам, разделяя их запятыми.

Comment: Пожалуйста обновите вопрос путем нажатия кнопки "Править", а не пишите комментарий к вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для нахождения целых чисел с запятой в качестве разделителя разрядов в тексте используйте

```
(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?![.,]?\d)
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/nsoPkK/1/).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!\d)` - сразу перед текущей позицией не должно быть цифры
- `(?<!\d[.,])` - сразу перед текущей позицией не должно быть цифры, за которой следует точка или запятая
- `\d{1,3}` - от 1 до 3 цифр
- `(?:,\d{3})*` -  запятая и три цифры
- `(?![.,]?\d)` - сразу после не должно быть опциональных точки или запятой, за которыми следует цифра

[Код на Python](https://ideone.com/xC56yx):

```
import re
numberRegex = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?![.,]?\d)')
mo = numberRegex.findall('41, 1,234, 6,368,745, 12,34,567, 1234')
print(mo)
# => ['41', '1,234', '6,368,745']
```

Comment: Кажется, решена более общая задача - поиск в тексте разрешенных чисел. "Подозреваю", что в этой, вероятно, учебной задаче надо просто отдельно проверять каждую строку.

Comment: @AlexTitov `.findall` используется как раз для поиска в тексте более коротких строк. Иначе всё гораздо проще, `re.match(r'\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$', s)`

Comment: Снимаю шляпу. Я ваше выражение только разбирал по документации 1,5 часа. Так как в книге, по которой иду, было сжато изложено о выражениях. Но лишним не будет знать доп. элементов нотаций регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 0):

Автор, вы про это?

```
import re

text = '"41", "1,234", "6,368,745"'

print(re.findall(r'"[\d,]+"', text))    # ['"41"', '"1,234"', '"6,368,745"']
print(re.findall(r'"([\d,]+)"', text))  # ['41', '1,234', '6,368,745']
```

---

**UPD.**

```
import re

text = '"41", "1,234", "6,368,745", "12,34,567", "1234", "123,456"'
print(re.findall(r'"(\d{,3}(?:,\d{3})*)"', text))
# ['41', '1,234', '6,368,745', '123,456']
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, ввел в заблуждение, на написал следующий доп. параметр: И не должны соответствовать следующие: "12,34,567", "1234"

Comment: @Ronin, не нужно так делать -- менять условие вопроса, когда ответ уже есть :(